# Extract feature weights of a linear regression in Azure Machine Learning Studio

Tags: r, azure, azure-machine-learning-service, ml-studio

Currently, we can only view the feature weights (or coefficient estimates) of a trained linear regression through 'visualize' option but not possible to save this as a table or dataset.
I am experimenting on a market-mix model to understand the incremental sales lift by each media variable, so I need to save the regression estimates.

Is there any workaround for this other than to use 'Execute R' module.

[image]

Comment: Can you use the Convert to CSV model on it to save the data?

Comment: no, I cannot connect the 'Convert to CSV' module block to the trained model block